# is the book wrong? solve $\int\frac{dx}{X^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int\frac{dx}{X^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$  i solved it by substituting $x=a\sec\theta$ i ended up with 
$\frac{a}{a^3}\int\frac{\sec\theta \tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta \tan\theta}d\theta$ so after the cancellation it becomes $\int\frac{d\theta}{\sec\theta}$ wich im pretty sure is the integral of cos x. so i integrate it and i get $\frac{1}{a^2}\sin\theta$ i back substitute using the tringle thing and i get $\frac{x}{a^3}$ , BUT the book says the answer in $-\frac{\sqrt {a^2-x^2}}{x a^2}$   i am thinking this would be the answer if the final integral was the integral of sinx not cosx . Any help?

Comment: If the book has $X$ and $x$ in the same formula, yet expects them to be equal, then YES INDEED the book is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made the correct substitution when returning to $x$; remember that $\sec{\theta} = 1/\cos{\theta}$, not $1/\sin{\theta}$.

Comment: Oh ok im sorry for the stupid question lol

Comment: As Rosannarosannadanna said:  "Nevermind."